# I want to filter my Author avatar list by by User role

Tags: php, wordpress, author, avatars

Here is my code. I only want to display The authors and exclude the rest of the user roles. Please help, I only have a few strands of hair left!!!!

```
function contributors() { global $wpdb;

$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");

foreach($authors as $author) 
{ 
echo "< li >"; 
echo "< a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author="; 
echo $author->ID; echo "\">"; 
echo get_avatar($author->ID, 125); 
echo ""; 
echo ''; 
echo "< a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author="; 
echo $author->ID; 
echo "\">"; the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID); 
echo ""; 
echo ""; 
echo ""; } }
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use `wp_list_authors`? (then you'd not need fetch all users, only to filter them down to authors) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how or where wordpress stores users roles, I suggest to use `get_role()` like this:

```
$realUser = wp_get_current_user();
foreach($authors as $author) {
    set_current_user($author->ID);
    if (get_role() != $authorRole) continue;
    set_current_user($realUser->ID);
    // ...
}
set_current_user($realUser->ID);
```

Comment: this is the error i got. Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in (url info) on line 2772

Comment: `set_current_user()` expects the ID. Edited my answer.

Comment: see what it's doing now. p.s. those user roles that you see are admin.  http://effinfamous.com/bloggers

Comment: okay... I added a new user. the one that says PJ is has an author role.

Comment: Why are you setting the current user with each loop, i thought the aim here was to fetch a result set of users that have the role of author..(are you reading something i'm not?)..

Comment: Because get_role() returns the role of the current user and I don't know how to select only the authors.

Comment: do you have a solution t31os?